# Join two columns based on ordering with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to find a query that can JOIN two tables using several shared columns, plus two incrementing columns *that don't share the same value* but follow some order. I am struggling to explain this problem in plain English, so here is an example:

The first table, items, looks like:

```
|id|user |period   |item_id|
|--|-----|---------|-------|
|01|1234 |January  |1      |
|02|1234 |January  |2      |
|03|1234 |January  |3      | 
|04|1234 |February |1      |
|05|1234 |February |2      |
|--|-----|---------|-------|
```

I'd like to join it to a table, charges, like:

```
|id|user |period   |charge_id|
|--|-----|---------|---------|
|01|1234 |January  |1072     |
|02|1234 |January  |1073     |
|03|1234 |January  |1074     |
|04|1234 |February |567      |
|05|1234 |February |570      |
|--|-----|---------|---------|
```

My goal is to find a query that results in:

```
|id|user |period   |charge_id|item_id|
|--|-----|---------|---------|-------|
|01|1234 |January  |1072     |1      |
|02|1234 |January  |1073     |2      |
|03|1234 |January  |1074     |3      |
|04|1234 |February |567      |1      |
|05|1234 |February |570      |2      |
|--|-----|---------|---------|-------|
```

One solution I considered was to use a temporary table or subquery to order charges and number them in a way that I can directly join on item_id.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE numbered_charges AS
  SELECT @row_num:=IF(@last_user=user AND 
                      @last_period=period, 
                      @row_num+1, 1) AS charge_number, 
         @last_user:=user as user, 
         @last_period:=period as period,
         charge_id
  FROM charges
;

SELECT charges.*, items.item_id FROM numbered_charges AS charges
JOIN items ON (charges.charge_number = items.item_id)
```

However, I'm concerned that this is not an efficient solution. This is a query that will be run regularly as part of a data integrity test, so avoiding unnecessary preprocessing is important. I expect pushback if I suggested adding the charge_number column to charges schema, which seems the ideal solution.

Does anybody have thoughts on the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Would joining on multiple columns using the `AND` operator help?

```
SELECT 
T1.id,
T1.user,
T1.period,
T2.charge_id,
T1.item_id
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.id=T2.id
AND T1.user=T2.user
AND T1.period=T2.period
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the item_id and charge_id are assigned by two different components of the system, and are not the same value. The only guarantee is that ordering by charge_id and ordering by item_id will join the correct records, but I can't do a simple join on charge_id = item_id

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id,
user,
period,
charge_id,
item_id
From items
Left join charges on(items.id = charges.id)
```